# sqlite database practice in android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have made an application simple in android for database practice,as i have no idea about `Sqlite database` I've gone through so many links for it,But most of them are complex,I have created 4 activities 1st (mainActivity) contains 3 `Buttons` "add","Edit", and "View" in 2nd activity (AddActivity) I have made 3 `EditTexts` its entered values should be stored in database.So can you please tell me easy steps for doing same?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.db;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button view=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub]
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }

    }
```

**AddActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.db;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddActivity extends Activity {
EditText name,addres,phon;
Button ad,cn;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        addres=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        phon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);

        ad =(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        cn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        final SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists simple(name varchar,address varchar,phone varchar");
        ad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            String n=name.getText().toString();
            String a=addres.getText().toString();
            String p= phon.getText().toString();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db.execSQL("insert into simple values('n','a','p')");
                Cursor c =db.rawQuery("select * from simple",null);
                c.moveToFirst();

            }
        });

        cn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i =new Intent(AddActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:text="View" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Add.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="phone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're asking how to store a value in SQLite?

Comment: yep...brother...by simple way..

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: http://techblogon.com/android-development-tutorial-for-beginners/#... covers pretty much all the basics for android development very well (used it myself to learn). Go to section 9 to view sqlite tutorial

Comment: @Raghunandan-I ahve gone throuth it but...not useful...!can you please tell me how single edittext value can be stored in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I think you want to add the value of edit text into your db

```
 package com.example.databasesample;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
static EditText edtAdd;
Button btnAdd, btnShow;
ListView listName;
static DataBaseSqlLiteHelper mBaseSqlLiteHelper;
DBModel mDbModel;
ArrayList<DBModel> mArrayList;
ListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();

    mArrayList = new ArrayList<DBModel>();
    mBaseSqlLiteHelper = new DataBaseSqlLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
    mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

public void initialize() {
    edtAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEnterName);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);
    listName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listName);
    listName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            deleteItem(mArrayList.get(arg2).getId());

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAdd:
        addName(edtAdd.getText().toString());
        break;
    case R.id.btnShow:
        showNames();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
    // for adding values
public void addName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase mOpenHelper = mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues mContentValues = new ContentValues();
    mContentValues.put("name", name);
    mOpenHelper.insert("NAMES", null, mContentValues);
    mOpenHelper.close();
}
    //showing values in list
public void showNames() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM NAMES";
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            mDbModel = new DBModel();
            mDbModel.setId(mCursor.getString(0));
            mDbModel.setName(mCursor.getString(1));
            mArrayList.add(mDbModel);

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, mArrayList);
    listName.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
     deleteing values
public void deleteItem(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String delete = "Delete from NAMES Where _id =" + id;

    mDatabase.execSQL(delete);
    mDatabase.close();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mArrayList.remove(id);

}
    //updating item
public static void updateItem(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String update = "Update NAMES set name=\""
            + edtAdd.getText().toString() + "\" where _id=" + id;
    mDatabase.execSQL(update);
    mDatabase.close();
}
```

}

```
 package com.example.databasesample;
 public class DatabaseConstants {

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE NAMES("
        + " _id integer primary key autoincrement," + " name VARCHAR"

        + ")";
```

}

```
  package com.example.databasesample;
  import android.content.Context;
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  public class DataBaseSqlLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "My Sample DataBase";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DataBaseSqlLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    db.execSQL(DatabaseConstants.CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE_QUERY);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

```
  package com.example.databasesample;
  public class DBModel {
String id;
String name;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

```
  package com.example.databasesample;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context mContext;
ArrayList<DBModel> mArrayList;

public ListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<DBModel> models) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mArrayList = models;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent,
                false);
        TextView txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
        txtId.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getId());
        TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getName());
        Button btnUpdate=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.updateItem(mArrayList.get(position).getId());
            }
        });

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
//activity_main.xml

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtEnterName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Name" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtEnterName"
    android:text="Add to Database" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:text="Show" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnShow" >
</ListView>
```

```
//listlayout.xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtId" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
    android:text="Update" />
```

Here I make an app in which you can add ,edit and update your database.i use Two main classes First DataBaseSqlLiteHelper.java to create databse and DatabaseConstants.java to create table. To delete item from db click on list and for update first enter value in edit text.comment on this if you need further help.

Comment: Thanx.....Rishab...Bro...ListView is ok..But can you please tel me how to store EditText value in database and from database how to get it and display it in textView?

Comment: hello friend If you go through with this app I have done the same as you want and mention in above question.I store the value of my edit text in database by clicking the button add to database.And If you want to show that value in a textvie you can show by giving the column index of that database.I think you need to study more about database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want only a single value to show on database then you can do like this
take a textView

```
TextView txtName;
```

initialize it in my above method of initialize();
then make a method to get single value

```
   // Getting single Name to textView
public void getContact(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mBaseSqlLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String select="Select name from NAMES Where _id ="+id;
    Cursor mCursor=db.rawQuery(select,null);
    if (mCursor!=null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name=mCursor.getString(0);
        txtName.setText(name);
    }
    db.close();
}
```

then call this method on the click of some button and pass the id of the row you want to select.